# How to get device lock and unlock even when the application was killed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, device

Enabled background modes on
I was getting device lock and unlock state when the application is in background or foreground.But not abled to get state when the application was killed. 
How to get the state even when the app was killed?

Comment: It is not possible!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in iOS.

We can detect only application background, foreground, suspend and terminate

Comment: if the application is in background then I am able to track device lock or unlock only for 3 mins, after that I am not able to detect status of device state.